# The option `lty` in `plot()` not working

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to generate a plot as interrupted line. But to my surprise the option `lty=2` in the function `plot()` doesnt work:

```
plot(1:10,lty=2)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why would it? You are drawing *points*. `lty` only affects the drawing of lines. It does work if you do, for example;

```
plot(1:10, type = "b", lty = 2)
```

which gives

[image]

I chose `type = "b"` here to illustrate the difference; it means *both lines and points*. Notice how `lty` affects the line parts, but not the points themselves. If you look at `?plot.default` you'll see

```
 plot(x, y = NULL, type = "p",  xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL,
      log = "", main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,
      ann = par("ann"), axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes,
      panel.first = NULL, panel.last = NULL, asp = NA, ...)
```

which indicates the `type = "p"`, for points, is the default if not specified by the user.

The points are drawn using a font character or glyph, not a line wrapped into a circle. These characters for the points are like any other text character on the plot (the axis and tick labels for example). As they are not drawn using lines `lty` does not affect them.

`symbols()` is an alternative function that *does* draw points using lines. For example

```
plot(1:10, type = "n")
symbols(1:10, 1:10, circles = rep(0.1, 10), lty = 2, inches = FALSE, add = TRUE)
```

which produces

[image]

You don't need the separate `plot()` call, just leave out the `add = TRUE` part of the call to `symbols()`, but if you do that, it gives different axes limits on the plot compared to the one you got with `plot()` above.

```
symbols(1:10, 1:10, circles = rep(0.1, 10), lty = 2, inches = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify that you want to plot lines with `type="l"`. By default `plot` will use points.

```
plot(1:10,lty=2,type="l")
```